# Qt: Properly use QNetworkReply?

Tags: c++, qt

How to properly use the QNetworkReply? I have seen example like this:

```
void HttpDownload::on_downloadButton_clicked()
{
    // get url
    url = (ui->urlEdit->text());

    // get() method posts a request
    // to obtain the contents of the target request
    // and returns a new QNetworkReply object
    // opened for reading which emits
    // the readyRead() signal whenever new data arrives.
    reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));

    // Whenever more data is received from the network,
    // this readyRead() signal is emitted
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()),
            this, SLOT(handleFinish()));
}
```

Is it possible that the finished signal is emitted before the connection is build?

Comment: Do you have more than one thread?  If no, it's not possible for the signal to be omitted until you cede control to the event loop.

Answer (score 0):

Check also errors

```
connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(networkErrorSlot(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
```

I think that finished signal is emitted also in the error situations and it may look like finished is emitted before the connection is built.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. The `finished` signal is emitted as soon as the connection cannot proceed anymore and will not be emitting any more signals. The signal's meaning is, essentially "I'm done emitting signals and my state is now set". Any unrecoverable error condition will, by necessity, end in the emission of the `finished` signal.